# Plone Review Portlet not shown

Tags: plone

Can anyone tell me how I get the pa.portlet Review-Portlet working?
Installed useng @@manage-portlet, but nothing is displayed...
(I have some items with state "pending")

I tried following versions

Plone 4.3.4.1
plone.app.portlet 2.5.2

Plone 5.0.2
plone.app.portlet 3.1.3

Comment: Do you see items in your review queue in your user dashboard?

Comment: Shouldn't useful point the user to the travis part which shows that this usercase is working in Plone? I this way, inspecting the test, the user can learn if it is doing what is expected from the system.

Comment: Yes, I am Review, or Site-Admin, its regardless

Comment: Look here for more details: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1969